# GCP Storage Log Bucket ACL access of Legacy Bucket Writer (GO SDK) Error 400

Tags: go, logging, google-cloud-platform, storage

I am trying to give my bucket-logs ACL access of Writer as suggested [here](https://download.huihoo.com/google/gdgdevkit/DVD1/developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs.html).

> gsutil acl ch -g cloud-storage-analytics@google.com:W gs://my_logs

I am using Go SDK v 1.10.0. Here is the Go code:

```
bucket_log := client.Bucket(logBucketName)
if err := bucket_log.ACL().Set(ctx, "cloud-storage-analytics@google.com", storage.RoleWriter); err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Failed to Give ACL access on Logging bucket %s.\nError: %s", logBucketName, err.Error())
}
```

But I am getting following error:

> Error: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid Value, invalid

But if I change "cloud-storage-analytics@google.com" into storage.AllAuthenticatedUsers, then it runs fine. Can anybody point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage@v1.10.0#ACLEntity), it was mentioned to use group-<email>. So, now the code now looks like this.

```
if err := bucket_log.ACL().Set(ctx, "group-cloud-storage-analytics@google.com", storage.RoleWriter); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed to Give ACL access on Logging bucket %s.\nError: %s", logBucketName, err.Error())
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation? Google typically uses `group:serviceaccountemail` and not `group-serviceaccountemail`.

Comment: @JohnHanley, here is the link https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage@v1.10.0#ACLEntity

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you.